# how to remove a preview image only one before upload in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This code is to preview image and I want to remove a preview image one of the many and remaining images still there before upload.

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImagePreview(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#imgViewer').append($('<img>', { src: e.target.result, width: '50px', height: '50' }));

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to remove a specific image not all images remove @Mohit Kumar

Comment: I used Button for remove image @Mohit Kumar

Comment: Actually, I don't understand where I put button for remove image. So, Please help me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6UP5/603/ check this, you can add some style to button

Comment: Thanks .. I'll try this @Mohit Kumar

Comment: This code doesn't work. Have you another code for this same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this using your code, there is an alternative for what you want. You just need to do it with the help of
[JQuery MultiFile](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/#Install), download it and reference on the page where you are going to upload files, you need to select one file at a time, before uploading you can browse multiple files and cancel whatever file you want. Complete code would be like this:

Reference of MultiSelect JQuery:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
```

`.aspx` code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" class="multi" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload Images"
        onclick="Upload_Click"/>
```

`.cs` code:

```
    protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
      for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
      {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        {
          hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("MyFiles") + "\\" +
          System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
          Response.Write("<b>File: </b>" + hpf.FileName + " <b>Size:</b> " +
                            hpf.ContentLength + " <b>Type:</b> " + hpf.ContentType + " Uploaded Successfully <br/>");
        }
     }
   }
```

[image: Sample]

It is a tested code, it works perfectly to address your problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to remove one image from many before upload. I give an option to a user to remove an image before upload all images

Comment: You mean, user selects more than one image and if user wishes, he could delete one or more from them, right?

Comment: Yes @M Adeel Khalid

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: In .cs code, this code upload remaining images after cancellation image before upload.. Right?

Comment: Right. It will upload rest of images.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adeel Khalid

Comment: If, I want to remove the image from javascript.?? What are the code this same.?